# Always run a particular file, one that isn't the current file in VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code

When you select "Run" from the menu, VS Code will run the current file.

But when I'm writing a Python package, the current file is almost certainly one of the module components of that package. These aren't the files I'm trying to run.

To test a package, I have a Python script that loads the package and runs some code on it. I generally am not editing that particular file at the time, since the actual work is being done in the package.

Is there a (hopefully per-workspace) option for making the file that gets executed the same regardless of exactly what file you're currently looking at when you want to run? That is, I don't want to run the current file; I want to conceptually run the *workspace*, the project that the workspace represents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VS Code has a feature called "configurations". These define what happens when you initiate debugging. They can be set on the workspace level.

The `Run->Add Configuration` command can be used to add configurations to `launch.json`, which can be associated with a particular workspace. For Python launching, the "Python file" launch style looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "Python: Current File",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${file}",
    "console": "integratedTerminal"
},
```

The `program` field specifies which Python file gets executed. So if you want to create a launch style that executes a specific file, simply modify this field to point to this file (and change the `name` to something more appropriate).

Answer (score 1):

To be more specific, after you create the launch.json, change the "program" item, like example below. It will always run the app.py

```
{
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/app.py",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
}
```